# GIMP can't access plug-in folder

Tags: nautilus, root, gimp

Ok, I want to access the plug-in folder in GIMP and I got this message. What is this?

**Can't show file in file manager: Calling ShowItems failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.207" (uid=1000 pid=20967 comm="/snap/gimp/393/usr/bin/gimp " label="snap.gimp.gimp (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.FileManager1" member="ShowItems" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.209" (uid=1000 pid=21056 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add plug-ins, put them in your own user plug-in folder (`~/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins`)(see `Edit > Preferences > Folders > Plug-ins for the list of folders that can be used).

If you are going to live with snaps, you can just as well use the flatpak version distributed by the Gimp team, at least it can use some popular plugins also distributed as flatpaks, and it will be the latest version.

Comment: Thank you!, I uninstalled Gimp from SnapStore and installed it using Terminal. That is the way. :P

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Gimp and re installed via Terminal.